Error: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease' is not signed
I got the following error:
E: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling InRelease' is not signed



Those with close votes - this question is actually on-topic, since it's Katoolin3 on Ubuntu.

This question is similar to: How do I fix the GPG error "NO_PUBKEY"?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The keyserver with the archived version of Katoolin3 appears not to be working.
Instead, install Katoolin3 from jspinella /
katoolin3, which has fixed the keyserver issue.
This is the commit that fixes the issue.
